# select 2 columns same table with different where clause

Tags: sql

I have data like

a-b where c = 1
a-b where c = 2

how to select 2 columns same table with different where clause

i have try
select (select a-b from t where c = 1),
(select a-b from t where c = 2)
from t

Thank u

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: `select a-b from t where c = 1 or c = 2` ?  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0e4feb39bda78ff39ca264698e551b3b)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when c = 1 then a - b end),
       max(case when c = 2 then a - b end)
from t;
```